# change according to dark mode

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I make it so that drawables and objects in MainActivity.xml change colour depending on if dark mode is on or not? I have this in colors.xml:

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#141414</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#C923FE</color>
<color name="textColor">#9719BF</color>


<color name="colorPrimary2">#81CDC9</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark2">#A8F8F3</color>
<color name="colorAccent2">#3C3C3C</color>
<color name="textColor2">#6E6E6E</color>
```

I want the second set of colours to be set in light mode, and the first in dark mode. My styles.xml consists of this:

```
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textColor</item>
</style>


<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent2</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary2</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/textColor2</item>
</style>
```

If my drawables and components in MainActivity access their colours with something like

```
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

then is there a way for me to change the pallete of the app if dark mode is on/off? Is there something i'm missing from all the tutorials i've seen, where I have to do something special to the MainActivity.xml components and drawables so they can access colours a different way? Thanks :)

Comment: read this document https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not need to duplicate colors and drawables. Just create -night folder like **drawable-night** and **values-night** etc.

Then put same files with same name (colors.xml/drawable files).

Sample:

**values/colors.xml**

```
<color name="colorDefaultText">#757575</color>
```

**values-night/colors.xml**

```
<color name="colorDefaultText">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember that `Dark Mode` is not `Night Mode`. They are completely different. DM was introduce in Android 10 that enforce built-in black and white color while NM was on earlier version that uses either default/defined style depending on your implementation. If you want your app to use your define light/night style and not relying on built-in dark style, you may want to `forceDarkAllowed` to false in themes.xml or style.xml as DM may conflict.