# How to change Status bar color

Tags: java, android, user-interface, themes, statusbar

In my app, when I use light theme it work fine , but when I use dark theme it work like expected for all except status (primary dark color) bar still light ..
How to change it to be dark in dark mode ...
[Here is what currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nov16.jpg)

How to make **primary dark color** to have one light color in light theme and another dark color in dark mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change according to dark mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61975468/change-according-to-dark-mode)

Answer (score 0):

This might work. It's working for me.

Method Body

```
// Method Definition
public static void blackIconStatusBar(Activity activity, int color) {

    activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color));

}
```

Call the Method

```
// set StatusBar Colour
blackIconStatusBar(this, R.color.white_grey_lite);
```